# Crontab can't loop

Tags: shell, cron

When I type the following in a terminal `./DHT 11 4` it works and saves all data to mysql correctly.

```
id (1), temp (29), hum (37), date (2015...)
```

When I add it to a crontab it does not work correctly.

```
id (1), temp (0 or empty), hum (0 or empty), date (2015...)
```

sh script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#DHT11
SCRIPT="/var/www/ErnestynoFailai/scripts/DHT 11 4"
#DHT22
#SCRIPT="/root/to/folder/DHT 22 4"
#AM2302
#SCRIPT="/root/to/folder/DHT 2302 4"
TEMP_AND_HUM=""
while [[ $TEMP_AND_HUM == "" ]]
do
    TEMP_AND_HUM=`$SCRIPT | grep "Temp"`
done
TEMP=`echo "$TEMP_AND_HUM" | cut -c8-9`
HUM=`echo "$TEMP_AND_HUM" | cut -c21-22`
myqsl_user="root"
myqsl_pw="pw"
myqsl_database="DHT"
today=`date +"%Y-%m-%d %T"`
query="INSERT INTO DHT11 (temp, hum, date) VALUES ('$TEMP', '$HUM', '$today');"
mysql --user=$myqsl_user --password=$myqsl_pw $myqsl_database << EOF 
$query
EOF
```

And crontab:

```
*/1 * * * * /var/www/ErnestynoFailai/scripts/write_DHT11_to_db.sh
```

What can be wrong?

Comment: have you tried debugging it? Set debug (`set -x`) and redirect the standard error to a log file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Long time ago, it happened on some systems that `cron` didn't start shell scripts, only binaries. So you had to indicate **explicitely** which interpreter to use in the crontab line

```
 */1 * * * * /bin/bash /var/www/ErnestynoFailai/scripts/write_DHT11_to_db.sh
```

I didn't check since, and I dont know what system you are using. On debian/jessie, it is told in the crontab 5 manpage that the command is executed by `/bin/sh`, or the shell specified by the `SHELL` variable in the `crontab` file.

See https://superuser.com/questions/81262/how-to-execute-shell-script-via-crontab

Comment: That's very unlikely to be the problem. The script in the question has a proper `#!/bin/bash` line at the top, and the crontab executes it directly. The command `.../write_DHT11_to_db.sh` is fed to `/bin/sh` to be executed, but sh (or rather the kernel) will honor the `#!/bin/bash` and use `/bin/bash` to execute the script. The whole point of the `#!` mechanism is that scripts can be interchangeable with binary executables.

Comment: Oh, thanks. It works with:
*/1 * * * * /bin/bash /var/www/ErnestynoFailai/scripts/write_DHT11_to_db.sh

I'm using RASPBIAN Debian Wheezy.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have a problem of different environment settings. For debugging, an easy way is to include a line like the following to the beginning of your script:

```
set >/tmp/envlog.txt
```

Then compare its contents once created when you run your script directly and once using crontab.

Another way for debugging is:

```
exec >/tmp/scriptoutput.txt 2>&1
set -x
```

With this commands, the full output of your script will be redirected to the specified file.

Most often, the PATH variable is wrong. Instead of

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

You often only have a reduces version of it:

```
/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

This means that some commands cannot be found. If you find a command which doesn't work, try finding out where it is located using:

```
$ which mysql
/usr/bin/mysql
```